# PHP Upload image,rename image with date timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

When i do this for this part here:

```
$ran = time();

   $ran2 = $ran."."; 

   It is able to set the image name as this: <br> 
   The file has been uploaded as 1379496233.67485,10.jpg <br>
   where by *1379496233 refers to the time();

   But when i do this: <Br>
   $ran = date("g:i:s A D, d/m/y");
   date_default_timezone_set('Singapore');

   $ran2 = $ran.".";  <br>
```

Error code such as this

`"Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/9:28:13 AM Wed, 18/09/13.1185810_10201356273602710_1568954903_n.jpg) [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\v.php on line 35"`

&
this occurs

`"Warning: move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php3E46.tmp' to 'images/9:28:13 AM Wed, 18/09/13.1185810_10201356273602710_1568954903_n.jpg' in C:\wamp\www\zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\v.php on line 35"`

```
  <?php
     //This function separates the extension from the rest of the file name and returns it 
     function findexts ($filename) 
     { 
         $filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
         $exts = explode("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
         $n = count($exts)-1; 
         $exts = $exts[$n]; 
         return $exts; 
     } 

     //This applies the function to our file  
     $ext = findexts ($_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 

     $ran = time();

     $ran2 = $ran.".";       

     //This assigns the subdirectory you want to save into... make sure it exists!
     $target = "images/";
     //This combines the directory, the random file name, and the extension
     $target = $target . $ran2.$ext; 

     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
     {
         echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$ran2.$ext;
     } 
     else
     {
         echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Date timezone should be: `Asia/Singapore` instead of `Singapore`

Comment: oh okay thanks, i think i just figured out the solution.Closed

Comment: The solution i just found.But it seems that the time zone is still wrong
$ran = date("g.i.s A D, d.m.y");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
$ran2 = $ran.".";